# ssh ポート転送機能がわかりません

Tags: ssh

下記のようにsshのポート転送を利用し、clientからsever_1（踏み台）経由でsever_2とTCPでの接続をする場合の
sever_1とsever_2のやり取りの部分がいまいちわかりません。

clientとsever_1の間でsshでの接続を確立し、それを利用してsever_1にTCP接続する。
そのあと、sever_1からsever_2にTCP接続されると思いますが、sever_1はどのようにしてsever_2に接続しているのでしょうか。sever_1からsever_2に対してのTCP接続を詳しく解説していただける方がいらっしゃれば、どうぞよろしくお願いします。

sever_1からsever_2にリクエストをリレーする部分の挙動がわかりません。

```
client <->  sever_1 <-> sever_2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

手順、コマンドではなく、通信の流れを知りたいということでしょうか？

例えば、HTTP (暗号化なし) を `LocalForward` することを考えます。
client から server_1 に `-L 8080:server_2:80` とした場合、client - server_1 間の暗号化接続が確立します。
(client の ssh プロセス、server_1 の sshd プロセスが起動)

```
    [client]$ ssh -f -N -L 8080:server_2:80 server_1

client(ssh) ======(暗号化)======> server_1(sshd)
```

client から 127.0.0.1:8080 へアクセスすると、LocalForward で起動済みの server_1 の sshd から新たに server_2 の 80 番ポートへ新規接続し、client からのパケットが転送されます。

client - server_1 間は暗号化された経路(トンネル)を通ります。
server_1 - server_2 間は暗号化されません。

```
    [client]$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/

client(ssh) ======(暗号化)======> server_1(sshd)
curl ---(HTTP/暗号化トンネル)--->                --(HTTP)--> server_2(httpd):80
```

HTTP 通信の終端は client(curl) と server_2(httpd) で、server_1 は TCP パケットを中継しているだけです。
server_2 から見ると、接続元は server_1 となり、server_1 の sshd はプロキシのように振る舞うとも言えます。

ちなみに、SSH を LocalForward すると、client - server_1 間は二重に暗号化されます。

```
    [client]$ ssh -f -N -L 10022:server_2:22 server_1
    [client]$ ssh -p 10022 user@127.0.0.1

client(ssh) ======(暗号化)======> server_1(sshd)
ssh ----(SSH/暗号化トンネル)---->                --(SSH)---> server_2(sshd):22
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: sever_1とsever_2はsshd(sever_2)によってTCPコネクションを張り続けいてるという認識でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: 1つめ、HTTP の例の場合、接続を受付・応答するのは server_2 httpd ですので、server_2 sshd は関与しません。
keepalive 有効なら TCP 接続を維持しますし、そうでなければ、リクエスト/レスポンスごとに TCP 接続をし直します。
2つめ、SSH の例の場合、server_2 sshd が TCP 接続を維持します。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

ポート転送 (ポートフォワーディング) を利用する際は、`ssh` コマンドを実行時に接続先として踏み台サーバと共に "最終的な接続先" もオプションで指定するので、この情報を元に踏み台サーバが良しなに処理してくれる…という説明で伝わりますか？

**実行例:**

```
$ ssh -L 22:server2:80 server1
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。私の説明不足で申し訳ないのですが、接続方法自体は存じておりますが、sever_1がsever_2へ実際に接続されるネットワーク層の動きを確認したい次第でした。

Answer (score 0):

SSHのポート転送で、sever_1経由でsever_2へSSH接続する方法です。

```
ssh ユーザ名@sever_2 -L 適当なポート:ユーザ名@sever_1:22
```

SSHのポート転送ではありませんが、sever_1経由でsever_2へSSH接続する別の方法です。

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh ユーザ名@sever_1 -W %h:%p' ユーザ名@sever_2
```

以下の環境で試してみました。PW認証です。
ローカル：WSL(ubuntu)
sever_1：CENTOS8
sever_2：CENTOS8

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。私の説明不足で申し訳ないのですが、接続方法自体は存じておりますが、sever_1がsever_2へ実際に接続されるネットワーク層の動きを確認したい次第でした。

Answer (score -1):

まず、クライアントからsever_1にSSHで接続し、シェルを操作できるようにしますよね？
そこから、sever_2にSSHで接続すればいいのです

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。私の説明不足で申し訳ないのですが、接続方法自体は存じておりますが、sever_1がsever_2へ実際に接続されるネットワーク層の動きを確認したい次第でした。